# Set new value to SQL

Tags: sql

I am new to databases. I want to retrieve user1 and update his age and phone values.

Can you give a couple options?

```
SELECT 
    account.user_name, 
    account.age, 
    account.phone, 
FROM 
    db.account   
WHERE  
    account.user_name  = 'user1';
```

Comment: Usually updates are done with `UPDATE`, not `SELECT`.

Comment: StackOverflow is a website for debugging and/or addressing code-related issues, not a learning service. I'd suggest following an introductory SQL tutorial to get started (there are thousands available online).

Comment: "I want to retrieve user1 and update his age and phone values." That needs to be two separate queries - an `UPDATE` and a `SELECT`.

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE myTable
SET Age ='var1', phone='var2', demographicX='var3'
WHERE user_name='user1'
```

[W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp)

[Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177523.aspx)

The select query in your question will give current values. update will update them

`demographicX='var3'` is a "fake" field made up. Given that this table seems to be a demographic table IE information about a person

Comment: what is demographicX?

Comment: just a "fake" field made up. Given that this table seems to be a demographic table IE information about a person.

Comment: @ShaneW - the content in your first comment looks like it belongs in the answer. Please **edit** your answer to contain that, and refer to the section [_When should I comment?_](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment)